# AngularJS app accessed from file:// protocol

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an AngularJS app that will have a hosted version and one that can be downloaded. The downloaded version should be accessible with 'file' protocol.

I've encountered several issues when trying to accomplish this. And have overcome quite a bit.

One issue that I am struggling with is enabling html5Mode on the hosted version, while disabling it on the downloaded file version.

Is it possible to set html5Mode based on what location protocol is being used?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that HTML5's `pushState` does not work when using the `file://` protocol. For example, it can be used fairly trivially as a phishing vector to try to point to something innocuous (or the other extreme: harmful).

Doesn't it make more sense to package the application into a "runner" of some sort? Even a Chrome application would be easier to handle app updates.